# Differential of distance function

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry

$X\subset \mathbb R^n$ is a compact  convex set, and $\partial X$ is smooth. $\omega \in \mathbb R^n/X$, and $p\in \partial X$ is the closest point of $\omega$. Let
$$
\psi: \mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R  \\
\psi(v) = dist(v,X)
$$
where $dist(v,X)$  is the distance from $v$ to $X$, if $v\in X$, then $\psi(v)=0$. Let
$$
L(v) = d\psi(\omega)(v-p)
$$
Then, how to show for any $v\in X $
$$
L(v)\le 0   ~~~?
$$
And, for any $v$ near $\omega$, there is
$$
L(v)\le \psi(v)  ~~~?
$$

Comment: $\psi$ may not be differentiable.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net   This problem origins from a geometric analysis book.  Maybe, it is not  rigorous. But I think ,if the boundary of convex set is smooth, then $\psi$ will be differentiable ?  I have edit it to smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4502775/is-a-distance-function-differentiable-on-bbb-rn/4502776) I asked about the differentiability and answered myself. I'm going to use the notation from that post. Partiularly, $\pi_X(w)$ is the closest point of in $X$ and $Y:=\{x:(x-p)\cdot e\leq 0\}$. We already know that $X\subset Y$ (see that answer). Forgive me but I'll be using $d_X$ instead of $\psi$.

From what we know from the above mentioned proof, $d_X$ is differentiable and $\nabla d_X(w)=\frac{w-p}{\|w-p\|}=:e$. Therefore

$$L(v)=\nabla d_X(w)\cdot (v-p) = (v-p)\cdot e.%=\frac{(w-p)\cdot (v-p)}{\|w-p\|}.$$

If $v\in X$ then $v\in Y$, so
$(v-p)\cdot e\leq 0$ and we get $L(v)\leq 0$.

To prove the second inequality let's take $v\in \Bbb R^n\setminus Y$. Therefore $(v-p)\cdot e>0$. We can therefore write $v=p+se+u_\bot$, where $u_\bot\perp e$ and $s>0$. Observe btw that $v=w$ if $s=\|w-p\|$ and $u_\bot=0$.

Now we see that
$$L(v)=e\cdot(v-p) = e\cdot(se+u_\bot)=s\|e\|^2+e\cdot u_\bot=s$$
and, since $\pi_Y(v)=p+u_\bot$ we have
$$d_X(v) \geq d_Y(v)=\|(p+se+u_\bot)-(p+u_\bot)\|=\|se\|=s.$$
Therefore $L(v)\leq d_X(v)$ for $v\in \Bbb R^n\setminus Y$.

Comment: Thanks your help.